# Drupal views filter exposed with condition fields

Tags: views

I have a page about buying/selling the car, on the views I have filter with by exposed function. My expected is, when I select the first category, the hidden sub level 1 category should be visible then the User can select level 1 category, we continue show the level 2. Then we make the filter with this filter.

For ex.

- All Categories
- Used Cars for Sale
- Motorcycles
- Boats

  1. [Selected [Used Cars for Sale]:
- Acura
- Honda
- Toyota
- Huynhdai...]

  2. [Selected [Motorcycles]
- Cruiser/Chopper
- Off-Road/Dual Purpose
- Sport Bike]

Select All Categories with Used Cars for Sale, 1 should show and 2 show invisible, select Motorcycles 1 should invisible and 2 should visible, and so on.

Click Filter, it should filter the current views.

It should be customize with the text, the range slide, the checkboxs... So what is the best modules or best way that I can do with the Views module?

Looking for somebody help me the solution

Kind regards,
John

Comment: Are you going to use one vocabulary for all products?

Comment: Mixing cars with motorbikes...maybe you should have a different View for every main vehicle type?

Comment: and boats also? You should rethink your architecture, IMO car, motorbike, boat = different content types, different Views and different exposed filters

Comment: @AlirezaTabatabaeian, it's one taxonomy with multi vocabulary levels.

Answer (score 1):

If you have planed to use just one vocabulary and you have designed it properly , then [Hierarchical Select Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) can help you to provide the functionality you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Functionality which you need, is in development phase, more info: https://www.drupal.org/node/1669940